# Jupyter Notebook Import Problems

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, pandas-datareader

I have problems importing python packages into Jupyter Notebooks. When I open notebooks from the anaconda prompt, nothing can be imported as shown below.

[import problem 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeWFh.png)

When I open Jupyter Notebook through the anaconda navigator. Most of the module imports work apart from pandas-datareader.

[import problem 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8mW7.png)

I do not know why pandas-datareader doesn't work because according to prompt it's installed but according to the list of packages in the navigator it is not (unless it's part of pandas).

[prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjiyv.png)

[navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K634q.png)

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: What is the output of `!pip freeze`? (You can run that straight from the notebook)

Comment: Sorry for the delay @CharlesLandau pandas 0.23.4, pandas-datareader 0.7.0, matplotlib 3.0.0 are all in there

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

Explicitly make a kernel from your env. Activate the env (e.g. with `source activate env`) then try:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"
```

[Ref](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments)

Restart the notebook, and look for a new option in the kernels dropdown

Second suggestion:

Import `datareader` before importing `datareader.anything`, and repeat that pattern across the notebook for all imports.

Comment: This might have made it even worse since now none of the imports work, even if I open it up with anaconda navigator. I'm not in a position to test suggestion 2 yet.

Comment: Are you selecting the kernel you created with ipykernel

Comment: And did you use your env name or did you leave in the placeholders like `myenv`

Answer (score 0):

Please try in your anaconda prompt

for python 2:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

for python 3:

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

and use anaconda prompt to open jupyter notebook and see. 
Hope it can help you.

Comment: I tried both commands, the requirement was already satisfied for both.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just do
#1 if you have environment activate it

```
conda activate yourenvname
```

#2 check if your libraries are there

```
conda list
```

#3 make a clean kernel

```
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

#4 open notebook or lab

```
jupyter notebook
```

Comment: This seems like it really should work... but it didn't. Do you recommend a completely new reboot & clean install of everything to do with Python? It will take a long time but hopefully, it will kill the issue. I also can't see other people getting this issue.